# Django-ads-txt causing ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: python, django, app-ads.txt

Hi I trying to Install django-ads-txt to my Django Project.

My first step was to `pip install django-ads-txt` then I added in the urls `path('ads.txt', include('ads_txt.urls')),` when I tried to `python manage.py migrate` I got the following error:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'
```

I tried to `pip install six` but the same error kept showing

My question: How to fix this error to install django-ads-txt?

Comment: looks like https://github.com/flyingelephantlab/django-ads-txt has not been updated in 4+ years, you will most likely need to downgrade your python/django versions to be compatible